# Docker workflow during development

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

While I work on setting up a network of linked docker containers, I find myself facing an issue that when I do docker run A ; docker run --link A:A B, and then later change A, I have to stop, rm and remake A, and then the 'link' in B will not work. For longer chains that means making any changes to A, even as minor as changing the restart policy or a mapped port, will result in me having to stop, rm and remake B, C, D, E ...

I understand that for production, Docker Compose is probably the tool of choice to deal with this, but I was wondering if there wasn't an easier solution during the initial development stages of a Docker network.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any PaaS to make it easier for e.g. [Convox](https://convox.com/docs/getting-started/)

It make the linking process easier

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - database
database:
  image: convox/postgres
  ports:
    - 5432
```